# How to make this sub-sub-query work?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am trying to do this in one query.  I asked a similar question a few days ago but my personal requirements have changed.

I have a game type website where users can attend "classes".  There are three tables in my DB.

I am using MySQL. I have four tables:

- hl_classes (int id, int professor,
  varchar class, text description)
- hl_classes_lessons (int id, int
  class_id, varchar
  lessonTitle, varchar lexiconLink,
  text lessonData)
- hl_classes_answers
  (int id, int lesson_id, int student,
  text submit_answer, int percent)

hl_classes stores all of the classes on the website.

The lessons are the individual lessons for each class. A class can have infinite lessons. Each lesson is available in a specific term.

hl_classes_terms stores a list of all the terms and the current term has the field active = '1'.

When a user submits their answers to a lesson it is stored in hl_classes_answers. A user can only answer each lesson once. Lessons have to be answered sequentially.  All users attend all "classes".

What I am trying to do is grab the next lesson for each user to do in each class.  When the users start they are in term 1.  When they complete all 10 lessons in each class they move on to term 2.  When they finish lesson 20 for each class they move on to term 3.  Let's say we know the term the user is in by the PHP variable $term.

So this is my query I am currently trying to massage out but it doesn't work.  Specifically because of the hC.id is unknown in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT hC.id, hC.class, (SELECT MIN(output.id) as nextLessonID
  FROM ( SELECT id, class_id
   FROM hl_classes_lessons hL
   WHERE hL.class_id = hC.id
   ORDER BY hL.id
   LIMIT $term,10 ) as output
  WHERE output.id NOT IN (SELECT lesson_id FROM hl_classes_answers WHERE student = $USER_ID)) as nextLessonID
FROM hl_classes hC
```

My logic behind this query is first to For each class; select all of the lessons in the term the current  user is in.  From this sort out the lessons the user has already done and grab the MINIMUM id of the lessons yet to be done.  This will be the lesson the user has to do.

I hope I have made my question clear enough.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Does the query produce an error?  Are the results wrong?  If so, how are they wrong - what are they, and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: I did mention that it doesn't run and I get an error but the specific error I get is: Error in query: Unknown column 'hC.id' in 'where clause'.  I know I can go something like SELECT *, (SELECT id FROM hl_classes_lessons WHERE class_id = hC.id LIMIT 1) as lessonID FROM hl_classes hC.  But this wont work, I assume it's because I went a layer deeper.  So I have been racking my brain trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You are getting that particular error because hC does not appear in the FROM clause (or is otherwise accessible) from that sub-sub query.

Comment: Can you please post the definition of the `hl_classes_terms ` table? also, please post how you want the results to look like.

Comment: @robertb not for the `hl_classes_terms` table...

Comment: @Scrum, yeah, realized that as I hit Add Comment :-/

Comment: @Josh I am not certain you are going to get what you want, even from Scrum's query. It seems to me that you either need to have the term id for each lesson identified in the lesson table, or if you are going to use the 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 scheme, then you need the class id in the answers table as a foreign key so you can reuse those numbers for subsequent classes (which implies that the primary key of the lesson table is id, class_id, rather than an autoincrement or something similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that you want a query that will tell what the next lesson is for a particular student for a given term, or null if there are no further classes for that student in that term. The result should be one row or null.

In order to do that with any efficiency (and IMHO, sanity) you need to revisit your table structure and assumptions about your data first. I am assuming from the table structures that you provided and how you described the lesson numbers, that there would be, for example, class 1, lessons 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11, ... 20, 21, ..., 30, and then class 2, lessons 1...30, and then class 3, lessons 1...30, etc. Further, lessons 1-10 for each class correspond to term 1, 11-20, to term 2, and 21-30 to term 3. Finally, terms are completed in order--class 3 lesson 10 is completed before class 1 lesson 11.

First, rather than using your class number as both a unique identifier and and ordering number (class 1 happens before class 2, etc), I would suggest a unique id field (probably an auto-increment), and a separate class_num field for the ordering number. (This is less critical for the classes table, than it is for the lessons table, described next.)

Next, and similarly, lessons should get a unique id field separate from it's lesson number field. The id would be the PK. This unique id is necessary to greatly simplify the query you want, as well as any other queries you might need. Without it you are dealing with a two-field composite key that makes many joins and subqueries nightmarishly complicated. You would probably want an additional unique index on class_id and lesson_num so that a lesson number is not re-used for a class. Also, this table should contain the term_num (or term_id) that a particular lesson for a particular class is assigned to. This will keep you from having to calculate what term a lesson is in using an overcomplicated MOD formula. That would be overkill. Just store the term number with the lesson information, and you can organize terms however you want.

Next, the answers table's id field should be a unique auto-increment. If it is important, you might also want a unique index on lesson_id and student_id *(although this means either no retakes, or retake overwrites)*.

So I now have:

- hl_classes (int id, int class_num, professor, class_name, description) PK: id, autoinc
- hl_classes_lessons (int id, int class_id, int lesson_num, int term_num, l_title, l_link, l_data) PK: id, autoinc; Unique Key: class_id, lesson_num
- hl_classes_answers (int id, int lesson_id, int student, ans, pct) PK: id, autoinc; Unique Key: lesson_id, student

With that, I came up with:

```
select hC.id as next_class_id, hL.id as next_lesson_id, hC.class as next_class, hL.term_num as term_num, hC.class_num as next_class_num, hL.lesson_num AS next_lesson_num
from hl_classes hC
left join hl_classes_lessons hL on hL.class_id = hC.id
where hL.term_num = $TERM_NUM
and hL.id not in (
    select hA.lesson_id
    from hl_classes_answers hA
    where student = $USER_ID
)
order by hC.class_num, hL.lesson_num
limit 1;
```

This will give you back either one row containing the relevant information about the next class for that student, given that term, or all nulls. Note that the ids are not for display, as they could be any ol' number. You would display the _num fields.

Comment: To get a list of all classes and lessons in the proper order for all terms, you would do the same select, from and left join, remove the where clause entirely, remove the limit, and the order by would be hL.term_num, hC.class_num, hL.lesson_num.

Comment: Thanks so much, it makes a lot of sense and answered everything.  When I learned about normalizing a DB I learned you dont want to have more information that you need to maintain than you have to.  Hence why I wasn't storing the "Term" because I figured every 10 belonged to each their nth respective term and that should be easy to calculate.

Comment: @Josh You're welcome. The next thing you learn after normalization is when to break those rules. There are lots of times you take a normalized design and denormalize it for performance, or convenience. You just have to do it with forethought so you don't get yourself into trouble. With respect to the term, I see putting the term in there actually as normalizing the data. Something you want to avoid is having one data element mean many things. Your lesson number defined 3 things: the lesson id, the lesson ordering, and the term (through algorithmic manipulation). That was at least 1 too many.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want the end result to look like, and why you have the LIMIT $term in your query, but if you want to get all the classes and the next lesson (if available) for the user you can use this:

```
SELECT c.*, l.*
FROM hl_classes c JOIN (
        SELECT l.class_id, MIN(l.id) NextLessonID
        FROM hl_classes_lessons l LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT sca.class_id, MAX(sca.lesson_id) MaxID
                FROM hl_classes_answers sca
                WHERE sca.student = $USER_ID
                GROUP BY sca.class_id
            ) cm ON (l.class_id = cm.class_id AND l.id > cm.MaxID) OR cm.class_id IS NULL
        GROUP BY l.class_id
    ) nid ON c.id = nid.class_id
    JOIN hl_classes_lessons l ON c.id = l.class_id AND l.id = nid.NextLessonID
```